# Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have created a simple web java application using gradle as build tool, hibernate/JPA as persistence framework and MySQL as database. The project builds successfully but when I test using postman the following error is encountered. btw my application is running in Wildfly 8.xxx and database schema is lm_db

Please see below:

```
19:18:41,451 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] 
(default task-2) HHH000327: Error performing load command : 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
19:18:41,460 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception 
handling request to /lm/rest/app/1: 
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1619)
   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1106)
   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1033)
   at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.find(AbstractEntityManager.java:213)
   at com.ph.lm.dao.GenericDaoBean.findById(GenericDaoBean.java:57)
   at com.ph.lm.endpoint.AppEndpointBean.getUserById(AppEndpointBean.java:30)
   at com.ph.lm.endpoint.AppEndpointBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getUserById(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
   ... 43 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:241)
   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:185)
   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
   at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3967)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2600(SessionImpl.java:164)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2696)
   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:975)
   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1075)
   ... 57 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "LM_DB" not found; SQL statement:
select user0_.id as id1_1_0_, user0_.password as password2_1_0_, user0_.privilege_id as privileg4_1_0_, user0_.user_details_id as user_det5_1_0_, user0_.username as username3_1_0_ from lm_db.user user0_ where user0_.id=? [90079-173]
   at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
   at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:616)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:623)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1075)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1713)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1821)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1707)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1550)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1538)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
   at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218)
   at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:428)
   at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:377)
   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:70)
   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:644)
   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:757)
   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:743)
   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:454)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
   ... 75 more
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_1.xsd"
version="1.1">

<persistence-unit name="lm_db_source" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.ph.lm.model.User</class>
    <class>com.ph.lm.model.UserDetails</class>
    <class>com.ph.lm.model.Privilege</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/lm_db" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1a0b1c6d0d6c1b3aA@"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", catalog = "lm_db", 
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"privilege_id", "user_details_id"}))
public class User implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 7751952716031714175L;

   private int id;
   private Privilege privilege;
   private UserDetails userDetails;
   private String username;
   private String password;

   public User() {}

   public User(Privilege privilege, UserDetails userDetails, String username, String password) {
       this.privilege = privilege;
       this.userDetails = userDetails;
       this.username = username;
       this.password = password;
   }

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
   public int getId() {
       return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id", unique = true)
   public Privilege getPrivilege() {
       return this.privilege;
   }

   public void setPrivilege(Privilege privilege) {
       this.privilege = privilege;
   }

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_details_id", unique = true)
   public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
       return this.userDetails;
   }

   public void setUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails) {
       this.userDetails = userDetails;
   }

   @Column(name = "username")
   public String getUsername() {
       return this.username;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
       this.username = username;
   }

   @Column(name = "password")
   public String getPassword() {
       return this.password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }

}
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

sourceSets {
 main {
     resources {
        srcDir 'src/main/resource'
     }
 } 
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.18'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.8'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.8'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
    providedCompile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.5'
    providedCompile 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:2.2.1.GA'
    providedCompile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
    providedCompile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

lastly,

[user table structure in MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oweCV.jpg)

Comment: `Schema "LM_DB" not found`. And that is executed in H2 database. So why do you refer to MySQL when you are using H2?

Comment: I also wondered why I always get org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException.. even though I am using MySQL.. I just checked the standalone.xml on my application server and it has a default datasource 

connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

but i didn't specify any datasource on my persistence.xml

Comment: so go back to where you defined your EntityManagerFactory in code, and why it is looking at a different persistence unit (because it is not using MySQL)

Comment: @BillyFrost you gave me a hint on why do I encounter the error.. I did some research and came across this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466824/wildfly-hibernate

Comment: you encounter the error because you are using H2 and not MySQL. It is then for you to work out WHY you are using H2, and you do that by looking at how you create the EntityManagerFactory.

Answer (score -1):

Check your db url.

My problem was from db url for connecton H2 db. It may be the same issue, database url.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```