# insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, datasource, mysql-8.0

wildfly version: wildfly-15
Hibernate version: Hibernate-5

```
  <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" spy="true" tracking="true" enlistment-trace="true" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource</datasource-class>
                    <connection-property name="useSSL">
                        false
                    </connection-property>
                    <connection-property name="characterEncoding">
                        UTF-8
                    </connection-property>
                    <connection-property name="serverTimezone">
                        GMT+8
                    </connection-property>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sample</user-name>
                        <password>sample</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "sample", name="person")
@Data
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * primary key and increment strategy
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer personId;

    /**
     * Field Constraint: no-null、length=32
     */
    @Column(nullable=false,length=32)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Integer age;

    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthday;
}
```

persitence.xml:

```
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
     <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
     <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"/>
     </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Error Info:

```
18:25:26,417 WARN  [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:649)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:212)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

Problem:
When I configure wildfly mysql datasource , when I login in wildfly management web ui, I can test datasource successfully, but when I package ejb project with jpa configure into a jar , then error info happens, How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Can you show your hibernate configuration? And please, do not link images with code. Instead, paste your code in the question.

Comment: Thank for tour suggestion. I adjust it. please see again.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot you attached it is clear that the error is

> No database selected

Apparently this occurs when your application does not know what database to use. to resolve this issue, you should change your database driver url from:

```
"URL"="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
```

to

```
"URL"="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename"
```

so check your database configuration file and add the database name also like below.

For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41550908/6572971)

**and avoid using the images ,use code instead.**

Comment: But,I have configure the whole database connect url: <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample</connection-url>, “sample” is my target database, I am a newer to jpa, is any error existing persistence.xml ?

Comment: yes something related to hibernate configuration file

Comment: can you give me an example persistence.XML?  mysql version  8.0

Comment: https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/jpa/hibernate5/src/test/bundles/explicitpar/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: The github example show transaction-type is "RESOURCE_LOCAL", but ,w I want to use defualt transaction-type "JTA" to manage datasource, it it not suitable for me